# How to return next string without >> with stringstream?

Tags: stringstream

Instead of:

```
stringstream szBuffer;
szBuffer>>string;
myFunc(string);
```

How do I do like:

```
muFunc(szBuffer.NextString());
```

I dont want to create a temp var just for passing it to a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the whole string in:

```
// .str() returns a string with the contents of szBuffer
muFunc(szBuffer.str());
// Once you've taken the string out, clear it
szBuffer.str("");
```

If you want to extract the next line (up to the next \n character), use [istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

```
// There are better ways to do this, but for the purposes of this
// demonstration we'll assume the lines aren't longer than 255 bytes
char buf[ 256 ];
szBuffer.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
muFunc(buf);
```

getline() can also take in a delimiter as a second parameter (\n by default), so you can read it word by word.